# How to get index of max value of array?

Tags: jquery

***SAMPLE VALUE A=0,B=1,C=2,D=3 From passed Input Value***

```
var data=[
  $('#a').val(),
  $('#b').val(),
  $('#c').val(),
  $('#d').val(),
];
```

***Getting Max Value***

```
 var getMaxValue=Math.max.apply(this,data);
```

> // Tried This but gives me -1 index //

```
 var getindex= $.inArray(max,getMaxValue);
```

Comment: See duplicate reference. Also realise that if `data` is numeric (you didn't specify a complete example, so we don't know), then it will not match (you'll get -1), because `.val()` returns a string, never a number.

Comment: @trincot thank you this gives me of idea converting to parse int

Comment: solved my problem ty

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var data=[0,1,2,3];
var getMaxValue=Math.max.apply(this,data);
var getindex= $.inArray(getMaxValue,data);
console.log(getindex);
```